# How to turn on the java smart editor?

Tags: eclipse, editor

Well I did something, but I do not know what.  In one java file in my project, but not the others, when I bring it up in the editor it looks like a plane text editor. It compiles when I save, but that is it.  How can I turn it back to the normal java smart editor?   And what did I do?  I am using the default eclipse editor. 
Thanks Cliff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the file, choose Open With -> Java Editor.

Eclipse remembers the last editor you used, and will use that if you simply double click the file.